# Fullstack Application in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS Amplify to host my entire full-stack application.
Now I need to use AWS DynamoDB as a Database.
The tech that I'm using to query is graphQL APIs.
I have the idea of using AWS AppSync in the case of graphQL APIs, but have no about where to add the code for the backend API in it, to query data from the database.

Thank You :)

Comment: I have been building an Android app with Amplify, and I found their documentation to be very helpful in standing up DynamoDB and graphQL features. [link](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/q/platform/android)

Comment: I have used the same documentation and the link for the same is https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/data-model/q/integration/react  but I'm unable to add custom GraphQL Resolvers to the Application, where should I write the code from the backend?